# How to visualize a parametric circle equation for a complex number?

Tags: graphing-functions

We know the parametric equation of unit circle:
$$\begin{cases}x=\cos(\alpha)\\ y=\sin(\alpha)\end{cases}$$
Now, let's assume $\alpha$ is **complex** number.

How will it look like? How to plot(visualize) it?

**Edit**: The range of $\alpha$ is $-5-5i$ to $5+5i$

Comment: Answers to [Plotting complex numbers as an Argand Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram) discuss a more general question. Just read the answers.

Comment: @Artes I think your question is not all compatible of my question. 
The target of your question is visualization of complex function for some real numbers,  so we have three scalars for output(complex number and input value).
In my question we has four scalar for output(two complex number), therefore we are talking about four-dimensional space but I don’t know how to visualize it.

Comment: That isn't  my question, while answers give you appropriate basis for solving your problem, at least examine my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram/15643#15643).  Given that there is no sufficient information in your post (what subset of the complex plane is your domain i.e. where does $\alpha$ belong?)  I gave just a reasonable hint. Instead of `F` in my answer  just use `Sin` and `Cos` on appropriate curve of whatever else your domain is. Anyway my suggestion should be quite enough to figure out further steps.

Comment: @Artes I added the necessary information

Comment: Still not clear as it should be. If you want to visualize an image of a square domain under  `Cos` and `Sin` see this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/möbius-transformations-revealed) or if you want an image of a  line segment under `Cos` and `Sin` then  my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram/15643#15643)  is the way to go. Anyway you will not visualize a four dimensional image.